# R - 2 dataframes, sum values on dataframe 2 between dates on dataframe 1 matching ID#

Tags: r, lubridate, sumifs, dplyr

I have 2 data frames.

```
data frame 1 includes : ID, date1, date2
data frame 2 includes : ID, date , amount
```

I want to create another column in data frame 1 that sums up the amounts in data frame 2 that are between `date1` and `date2` and `match ID` in data frame 1.

I have tried a few methods using dplyr, including creating an interval column in data frame one using `lubridate` but still cannot get this to work out.

Also, I should mention that data frame 2 has multiple listings for each ID. It has amounts for each day for each ID during the month. So its like a sumifs function in excel but for R. Sum all amounts in df2 if the id matches and the date is btw date1 and date2.

Comment: Please provide reproducible data along with question so that it will be easier for others to answer.

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` based solution could be as:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% left_join(df1, by="ID") %>%
  filter(between(date, date1, date2) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(sum_amount = sum(amount))
```

Note: Above solution assumes that `date`,`date1` and `date2` are of type `Date` or `POSIXct` type.

Comment: This is great ! But I cant join because there are more coloumns in df2 than df1.  df2 is the dispense for each id every day for a month. So we will see an ID listed 30 times

Comment: @ANN More columns in `df2` is not a problem. If I have understood you correctly you got many `df2` (1 for each day). That also is not a problem. You can use `bind_rows` to merge all `df2s` in one data.frame. Then you can join with `df1`. It would be better if you can share reproducible example and expected results.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. 

This is the error I receieve 
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: Expecting a single value: [extent=3054256]..
In addition: Warning message:
Column `NAME` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector

Comment: I cant share the data but I am trying to see how to share a sample of the data  one moment.

Comment: okay fixed part of the error working on the other part                         
                Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: Expecting a single value: [extent=352]

Comment: @ANN Can you share what you have written in `filter`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the fuzzyjoin package.

```
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 <- tibble(
  id = c("I1", "I2", "I3"),
  date1 = ymd(c("2006-01-01", "2007-01-01", "2008-01-01")),
  date2 = ymd(c("2006-12-31", "2007-12-31", "2008-12-31"))
)

df2 <- tibble(
  id = c("I1", "I1", "I2", "I2", "I3", "I3"),
  datetrans = ymd(c("2006-06-06", "2008-03-31", "2007-05-04",
                    "2007-08-09", "2009-01-01", "2009-10-12")),
  amount = c(100, 150, 75, 100, 200, 200)
)

df3 <- fuzzy_inner_join(df2, df1,
                        by = c("id" = "id",
                               "datetrans" = "date1", "datetrans" = "date2"),
                        match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`))
df3 <- df3 %>%
  group_by(id.x) %>%
  summarise(amount = sum(amount))
colnames(df3) <- c("id", "amount")

result <- left_join(df1, df3)
```

The datasets df1 and df2 are created. Note that for id I3, there are no "dates" which appear between date1 and date2.

We first find all records between df2 and df1 where the id's match and the datetrans variable is between date1 and date2. We group the results by id summing up the amount. Finally, this dataset is merged back to df1 to get the required output.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I receive an error, probably due to there being multiple rows that include the same ID number in df2. I should have specified that originally, sorry!                                               
            Error in Ops.factor(rep(u_x, n_y), rep(u_y, each = n_x), ...) : 
  level sets of factors are different

Comment: @ANN If you see my example tables, each of the id's appear multiple times in df2 so there is no problem with the above code. I guess the error is because the id is also a factor in your datasets which is why you get this error.

Comment: You are correct! Sorry for the confusion. I figured it out :) Thank you so much